# DIVs split into half and added as a child in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was asked this question during an interview recently.

Problem statement - Given a div of a certain width and height, keep appending divs to it, but size it down to half before the append. Do it until height/width is less than 10. Attached is my solution

```js
let toggle = true;
let border = 0;
container = $('.mainBox');
while (container.height() > 10 || container.width() > 10) {
  if(toggle) {
    container = splitVertically(container); 
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    container = splitHorizontally(container);
    toggle = true;
  }
}     

function splitVertically(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div>')
    .width(container.width()/2)
    .height(container.height())   
    .css('border-right', 'solid 1px');
  container.append($newElem); 
  return $newElem;
}

function splitHorizontally(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div>')
    .height(container.height()/2)
    .width(container.width())
    .css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px');
  container.append($newElem);
  return $newElem;
}
```

```css
.mainBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  /*   background: blue; */
  border: 1px solid;
}

.addBorder {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainBox"></div>
```

If I wanted to add the divs to right of parent how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: _"add the divs to right of parent"_ what does that mean? What parent are you talking about? Are you talking about adding divs outside to the right of `.mainBox`? Or just aligning the existing boxes to the right?

Comment: "add the divs to right of parent" can you please elaborate? If you wanted the pattern to be to the right you can do a transform: rotateY(180deg) on your .mainBox

Comment: My apologies, let me try again. I meant to say when you append the first div it goes to the left. I want to add it to right half of the parent div.

Comment: You should just be able to add `.mainBox > div { float: right; }` to your CSS. Also adding an answer that has a version that's more compact and doesn't rely on jQuery if you're curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by putting `border-left` and `float:right`

```js
let toggle = true;
let border = 0;
container = $('.mainBox');
while (container.height() > 10 || container.width() > 10) {
  if (toggle) {
    container = splitVertically(container);
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    container = splitHorizontally(container);
    toggle = true;
  }
}

function splitVertically(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div class="pull-right">')
    .width(container.width() / 2)
    .height(container.height())
    .css('border-left', 'solid 1px');
  container.append($newElem);
  return $newElem;
}

function splitHorizontally(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div class="">')
    .height(container.height() / 2)
    .width(container.width())
    .css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px');
  container.append($newElem);
  return $newElem;
}
```

```css
.mainBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  /*   background: blue; */
  border: 1px solid;
}

.addBorder {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainBox"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @brk this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `after` in place of `append` and also add a class name to the div you are adding and then in its style make `display: inline-block;` Check the below snippet in full page mode to see it in work.

```js
let toggle = true;
let border = 0;
container = $('.mainBox');
while (container.height() > 10 || container.width() > 10) {
  if(toggle) {
    container = splitVertically(container); 
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    container = splitHorizontally(container);
    toggle = true;
  }
}     

function splitVertically(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div class="mainBox">')
    .width(container.width()/2)
    .height(container.height())   
    .css('border-right', 'solid 1px');
  container.after($newElem); 
  return $newElem;
}

function splitHorizontally(container) {
  let $newElem = $('<div class="mainBox">')
    .height(container.height()/2)
    .width(container.width())
    .css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px');
  container.after($newElem);
  return $newElem;
}
```

```css
.mainBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  /*   background: blue; */
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.addBorder {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainBox"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float: left` to the CSS for your child divs will allow that. This version also shows an example that doesn't require jQuery

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.mainBox'), w = box.clientWidth, h = box.clientHeight

function px(val){ return [val, 'px'].join('') }

while(Math.max(w, h) > 10){
  let child = document.createElement('div')
  if(w > h) w /= 2
  else h /= 2
  child.style.width = px(w)
  child.style.height = px(h)
  
  box.appendChild(child)
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  /*   background: blue; */
}
.mainBox > div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox"></div>
```